# How to mirror a box around given point, not selection center

Tags: modeling, mirror

How can I set the location of the mirror tool? I followed the documentation and while I can set the axis of the operation the mirroring always happens at the center of the selection and I have no idea how to set it to somehere else.

Comment: in the Mirror modifier, there's a field called Mirror Object, you can create an empty that will be the center of the mirroring, is it what you're looking for ?

Comment: I'd like to mirror the selected polygons once, into the same mesh, so after that I can edit them in a way that breaks symmetry.

Comment: could you please show a drawing to make it clearer?

Comment: You could use the symmetrize tool with just the wanted faces selected to have those faces mirrored. However it gets mirrored locally but you could probably make it work that way and then you can edit it assymetrically

Comment: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=10So-WaYnx29KA7_aNOdzXlk4cuu9ERi-
Here you can see the mirror plane in the middle of the selection. I'd like to have it in the corner instead.

Comment: Is it Symmetrize or Mirror modifier that you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> mirror tool, in Object or Edit mode,  in any orientation, around any pivot-point.

- Set the pivot-point .. most likely '3D Cursor', or 'Active Element'
- Set the orientation .. if it's not conveniently Local, Global, or other preset, create a Custom Orientation from an edge, or two vertices. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> in 2.97, header orientation menu in 2.8)
- Locate the pivot-point, by <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> snapping the 3D cursor to the right place, or, in Edit mode, making an appropriate vertex from your selection active)
- Hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, and  <kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>Z</kbd>. If the orientation is not Global, but the currently selected secondary orientation, hit the dimension twice. (<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, etc.)

You can still go into the tool region to change the orientation, after left-clicking.

In Edit mode, you can achieve the same effect by creating a Custom Orientation from ant two vertices, making your selection, setting the pivot, and hitting <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

These are **axes** and they can't be moved. You move objects or, as below, origin.

Select the corner vertex. <kbd>Shift +S</kbd>> Cursor to selected. Finally, **Origin to 3D Cursor** and Mirror modifier.